# How to call a CUDA C app in Java through ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, cuda, processbuilder

I have a very complex application that uses CUDA and was write in C. This application is command-line only and now I want to build a GUI using Java Swing.

I don't want to rewrite C code, so I'm calling the command-line version using a ProcessBuilder object. This way I can read messages from it and show on a console inside the GUI.

This is the code I'm using:

```
String command = "myApp";
pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c",command);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process shell;
try {
        shell = pb.start();
        InputStream shellIn = shell.getInputStream();
        Drawer.writeToLog(convertStreamToStr(shellIn));
        shellIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public String convertStreamToStr(InputStream is) throws IOException{
    if(is != null){
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();

        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1){
            writer.write(buffer,0,n);
        }
        is.close();
        return writer.toString();
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

If I try something like "ls" command it works fine. However, for my app I get this error:

```
./myApp: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

CUDA is installed and properly configured in my machine, I can execute this app correctly from Terminal. I imagine that the error is from Java Virtual Machine.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure this library is in a directory in your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: The JVM may not be respecting the ordinary library load paths.  You might try copying libcudart.so to the location where myApp is located, and see if it can find it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me, I just tested it:

```
System.out.printf("[Starter#main] !\n");
final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("absolute/path_to/your/executable");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.environment().put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH",
    "/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib");
final Process start = builder.start();
final InputStream outputStream = start.getInputStream();
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputStream));
String s;
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.printf("[Starter#main] %s\n", s);
}
```

Gotchas:

1. Make sure your application bitness matches your toolkit.
2. Mac OS X variable is called "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Also note:

1. Spawned process will inherit environment from your Java process, that is it should work fine if you run Java application with PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH configured as advised by CUDA toolkit installer.
2. You may externalize variables setting and launching your app in a shell script - then all you have to do is just running shell with a given script.

Comment: You got it. Looks like you need to add: 

builder.environment().put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH","/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib");

To set the ProcessBuilder correctly. Thank you very much =)